# hadoop pig mapreduce distributed cach files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using hadoop1.2.1 and pig0.10. I have some jar files used in mapreduce job. So I copied jar files to hdfs in /tmp/lib path .Then in pig script i tried to add statement like SET mapred.cache.files /tmp/lib/file.jar; SET mapred.create.symlink yes;. But I got error as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. <line 1, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'SET'
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1597)
```

Comment: Finally I use registerJar method in pig to add jars for map-reduce mode. Now it works fine in hadoop cluster mapreduce mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET mapred.cache.files '/tmp/lib/file.jar'
```